# P/invoke conditional structures

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

Some structs in winapi have additional members in each windows version.

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
 int cbSize;
 int a;
 int b;
 #if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600
 int c;
 int d;
 #endif 
} MyStruct, *PMyStruct;
```

When I port this to C# is Ok to define all members (cbsize,a,b,c,d) and pass the struct as argument in some pinvoked function, or should I define a smaller struct for XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to support Windows XP, then you need to use only the fields defined in Windows XP.     The issue isn't directly the size of the structure, but the value of `cbSize`.  If it does not match a value that the API is expecting then the API call will fail.   So passing a cbSize of the larger Vista version of the struct will cause the API to fail (that is return a failure code, it won't crash).

If you need to you could detect the version of Windows that you are running on and pass in the size that there version of Windows expects (You can pass in the larger sized struct, Windows will just ignore the extra bytes)  But you only need to do that if you need to have `c` and `d` filled in on Vista+.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/12/56061.aspx) for the reasons why a sending in a larger `cbSize` are rejected.

Comment: If I pass the full struct with smaller cbSize, wouldn't c,d fields corrupt the other arguments of the function?  WinapiFunc(theStruct, arg2,arg3);

Comment: @albert, no because the API takes a pointer to the structure.  The only thing on the call stack is the pointer value - irregardless of the size of the struct being pointed to.  The p/Invoke definition should be using `ref struct` to indicate this.  See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowInfo.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516(v=vs.85).aspx